# Getting unexpected class when highlight menu using Angular.js and UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using UI Router for navigating the menu. When I am clicking on second menu it's getting the active class but still the first menu is highlighted. I am providing my code below.

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="product">Home</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{'active': $state.includes('product.eVouchers')}" class="dropdown"><a ui-sref="product.eVouchers.dashboard" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">E-Vouchers <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="product.eVouchers.dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
                  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="product.eVouchers.code">Generate Voucher Code</a></li>
                  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="product.eVouchers.list">E-Voucher List</a></li>
                 </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
```

When I am navigating to the second menu (`i.e-E-Vouchers`), at the same time the first menu is getting highlight with second menu. But when I am in the first menu only the first menu is getting the `active` class. Here I need when user will navigate to the any menu that menu only will get the active class.

I am using `ui-router` `@version v0.2.15`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of

```
<li ng-class="{active:$state.includes('product')}">
```

you add the class yourself for the parent menu so why don't you use the ui-sref-active like for other menus?

```
ui-sref-active="active"
```

Comment: @ maurycy : i did as per you still same issue is there.

Comment: odd, ui-sref-active should match the full route, in that case try `<li ng-class="{active:$state == 'product'}">`

Comment: Wait, what with this line: `ng-class="{'active': $state.includes('product.eVouchers')}"` that's on parent element to vouchers

Comment: @ maurycy : its done it should be `ng-class="{active:$state.current.name ==='product'}"`.

Answer (score 0):

ui-sref-active can live on the same element as ui-sref or on a parent element. The first ui-sref-active found at the same level or above the ui-sref will be used.

ui-sref-active will activate when the ui-sref's target state or any child state is active. If you need to activate only when the ui-sref target state is active and not any of it's children, then you will use **ui-sref-active-eq**